# Compare dates without seconds and milliseconds with LINQ in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to run this query, however I get an error saying that this query could not be translated.

I have tried subtracting seconds and milliseconds but the `StartDateTime` has some fractions of the millisecond that I couldn't eliminate.

While trying some options of truncating the seconds and milliseconds and ticks, I got the same error of NOT BEING ABLE TO TRANSLATE THE QUERY.

Is there any appropriate way of doing this query?

```
  await _context.AppointmentReminders
                .Where(x => x.RemindAt.ToString(@"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm") == request.StartDateTime.ToString(@"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm")
                            && x.IsHandled == false) 
                .Include(a => a.Appointment)
                .ThenInclude(a => a.AppointmentInvitations)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution was to compare the date, hour and minute each separately.

```
await _context.AppointmentReminders.Where(x => x.RemindAt.Date == request.StartDateTime.Date && 
                                                                                    x.RemindAt.Hour == request.StartDateTime.Hour && 
                                                                                    x.RemindAt.Minute == request.StartDateTime.Minute &&
                                                                                    x.IsHandled == false)
                                                                        .Include(a => a.Appointment)
                                                                        .ThenInclude(a => a.AppointmentInvitations)
                                                                        .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should be able to simply rework this as a range query.  EG

```
var d = request.StartDateTime;
var startDate = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, d.Minute, 0);
var endDate = startDate.AddMinutes(1);

await _context.AppointmentReminders.Where(x => x.RemindAt >= startDate && x.RemindAt < endDate
                                                  && x.IsHandled == false).Include(a => a.Appointment)
                                                  .ThenInclude(a => a.AppointmentInvitations
                                                  )
                                                  .ToListAsync();
```